# Unity3D Advertisement does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I switched from Unity Ads 3.0.1 to Unity Advertisement Legacy Package (4.4.2). I have deleted the Unity Ads package from the Asset folder and installed the Advertisement Legacy Package from the package manager. When trying to run this code, `UnityEngine.Advertisements.Advertisement.Initialize()`, I keep getting "Advertisement does not exist in UnityEngine.Advertisements" console error.

I have applied all solutions from [Info Gamer Fix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BG7L5101rpk).

Please how do i make the console error go away. Thank you.

Comment: Can you add the script you're having trouble with to the question? If you use the example script here https://docs.unity.com/ads/en-us/manual/InitializingTheUnitySDK does it work?

Comment: I just tested the example script here https://docs.unity.com/ads/en-us/manual/InitializingTheUnitySDK. It doesnt work. It says IUnityAdsInitializationListener, UnityAdsInitializationError, Advertisement could not be found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that if you have an assembly definition file in your Assets folder. You must add the Advertisement namespace to fix this issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).